# SQL Data Modify

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view with StudentName, GPA, Semester

```
        Name     GPA    Semester
          x        3.15   1
          x        2.89   2
          y        3.87   1
          y        4.0    2
```

I want to modify like this

```
     Name semester1 GPA  semester 2 GPA
       x        3.15          2.89
       y        3.87           4.0


 Any help would be appreciated.
 Thanks
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 3):

Use *conditional* aggregation:

```
select Name,
       max(case when Semester = 1 then GPA end) AS "semester1 GPA",
       max(case when Semester = 2 then GPA end) AS "semester3 GPA"
from table t
where Semester in (1, 2)
group by Name;
```

Comment: Great. Thank you.